# How generate custom form via vtiger field object?

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

Add below code in module/Edit.php

```
$query = 'SELECT f.* FROM vtiger_field as f
          INNER JOIN vtiger_tab as t on f.tabid = t.tabid and t.name=? 
          WHERE fieldname =?';
$result = $adb->pquery($query, array('{module_name}', '{field_name}'));
$num_rows = $adb->num_rows($result);
for($i=0; $i<$num_rows; $i++) {
         $row = $adb->query_result_rowdata($result, $i);
         $Field_Model = new Vtiger_Field_Model();
         $Field_Model->initialize($row);
}

$viewer->assign('FIELD_MODEL', $Field_Model);
```

Add below code in TPL file.

```
{include file=vtemplate_path($FIELD_MODEL->getUITypeModel()->getTemplateName(), $MODULE)}
```